# How to fix compiling Friday Night Funkin by ninjamuffin 99 from source code but there is no .exe after being compiled?

Tags: haxeflixel

I tried to compile the source code but there is no .exe https://i.stack.imgur.com/CY4jQ.png

I followed the instructions that is from github https://github.com/ninjamuffin99/Funkin and still it don't fixed it. When I tried to compile the source code in cmd after I typed in `lime test windows -debug` it shows this

```
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/polymod/git/polymod/format/XMLMerge.hx:189: characters 10-23 : Warning : This typedef is deprecated in favor of haxe.xml.Access
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/polymod/git/polymod/format/XMLMerge.hx:189: characters 30-43 : Warning : This typedef is deprecated in favor of haxe.xml.Access
source/PlayState.hx:299: characters 3-39 : Warning : `FlxCamera.defaultCameras` is deprecated, use `FlxG.cameras.setDefaultDrawTarget` instead
C:\Users\username\Downloads\FNF MODDING\Kade-Engine-master\Kade-Engine-master\export\debug\windows\obj>setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Warning: Could not find Visual Studio 2017 VsDevCmd
Missing HXCPP_VARS

Error: Could not automatically setup MSVC
```

can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling "Could not automatically setup MSVC" the [most common error](https://community.openfl.org/t/problem-building-for-windows/10960) seems to be failing to restart your PC after installing VS.

I've found that VS has a separate shortcut for "Visual Studio Command Prompt", are you using that rather than a generic command window?

Comment: I use Windows Powershell or Command Prompt to compile the source code

Comment: i kinda forgot to download the whole individual components from the instructions from github 'xd. Yeah. It works now. Ty for giving the " https://community.openfl.org/t/problem-building-for-windows/10960 ". It helps me a lot.

Comment: I don't know how useful this would be but there's an article here on how to build a HaxeFlixel game for Windows https://dev.to/richardbray/how-to-build-a-native-windows-project-in-haxeflixel-openfl-kd8